# How to Total Quantity using the Controller and return to view

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

Have a total sum of the `dr_quantity` in the controller and return to the view model

```
public function searchmedreport()
    {

        $search = \Request::get('search');
        $total = DB::table('distribution_records')->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->sum('medicine_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
        $records = DistributionRecord::whereRaw("Concat(dr_fname,' ',dr_lname) LIKE '%{$search}%' ")
        ->orWhere('medicine_name','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('date_requested','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orderby('id')->paginate(5000);

        return view('forms.searchmedreport',['records'=>$records,'total'=>$total]);
    }
```

and

```
<b><h4>Total Number of Medicine Distributed: {{$total}} </b></h4>
```

put the total in

Comment: What column do you want to calculate total value in the distribution_records table? It's surely not medicine_name, isn't it?

Comment: @Kevin Bui the total of dr_quantity and if I search for a specific medicine in the search bar and it will total the sum of that medicine...

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your table, you are performing a wrong query, so instead of this:

```
$total = DB::table('distribution_records')->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
             ->sum('medicine_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
```

You need this:

```
$total = DB::table('distribution_records')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
             ->where('medicine_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->sum('dr_quantity');
```